# Remove white shadow from BackdropFilter

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem I have is that `BackdropFilter` is applying the blur but on the top border of the child there is a white shadow ([screenshot with black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTs9X.png)).
The only way to remove it is to set `sigmaY=0` but the blur is not homogeneous.
How can I fix it?
This is the code so far:

```
return Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 5,),
              SizedBox(
                height: headerHeight,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: Image.network("https://coolbackgrounds.io/images/backgrounds/black/pure-black-background-f82588d3.jpg").image,//homeData.imageFromString.image,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ClipRect(
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 15.0),
                      child: Container( 
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Row(),
                            ),
                            CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 50,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                              backgroundImage: homeData.imageFromString.image,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              homeData.name,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Row(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Did you try setting elevation as 0 here?

Comment: Sorry, in which widget are you saying to add elevation=0?